# Controlling part of a mesh using NinevehGL

Tags: 3d, controls, mesh

I have a mesh in the form of a opera theater with speaker assemblies around the stage that I'm able to load and render using NinevehGL. I want to just control the positioning of the speaker assembly (in 3D space) without affecting the rest of the opera theater. Is this kind of intra-mesh control possible using NinevehGL? Thanks in advance.